# Application Keep Alive in shared hosting with no access to IIS Manager

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config

I am using GoDaddy's shared hosting. My website usually takes time to load every time when I open it after sometime. I came to know that Asp.net websites starts again after some time-out.

Then I came to know that we can Keep Alive our websites via IIS Manager. But I do not have access to IIS Manager as I am using Shared hosting. Can I still keep alive my application every time?

Do we have any settings in web.config to keep application alive?

Comment: Since it's not programming, but about server configuration, it would belong to Server Fault. I'm flagging it to be transferred there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Atlast i got a solution on another website : here's the link [Keep alive IIS without accessing IIS manager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39118/Keep-Your-Website-Alive-Don-t-Let-IIS-Recycle-Your)

In case if link is destroyed. I will explain it here:

Add this code to your global.asax file and call it in App_Start which will automatically keep alive your website by running a simple refreshing job.

```
private static void _SetupRefreshJob()
{
   //remove a previous job
   Action remove = HttpContext.Current.Cache["Refresh"] as Action;
   if (remove is Action)
   {
       HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove("Refresh");
       remove.EndInvoke(null);
   }
   //get the worker
   Action work = () =>
   {
       while (true)
        {
          Thread.Sleep(60000);
          WebClient refresh = new WebClient();
          try
          {
           refresh.UploadString("http://www.websitename.com/", string.Empty);
          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
                    //snip...
          }
          finally
          {
            refresh.Dispose();
          }
      }
  };
  work.BeginInvoke(null, null);

  //add this job to the cache
  HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(
  "Refresh",
  work,
  null,
  Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
  Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
  CacheItemPriority.Normal,
  (s, o, r) => { _SetupRefreshJob(); }
  );
}
```